# In the WinForms DevExpress XtraWizard control, how can one hide the back button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I know that if I set the WizardStyle of an XtraWizard control to *WizardAero*, it will remove or hide the back button from the first page instead of simply disabling it, as can be seen [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4723).  I want the same behaviour, but I want to keep the WizardStyle as *Wizard97*.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the `CustomizeCommandButtons` event on the WizardControl.

```
    private void wizardControl1_CustomizeCommandButtons(object sender, CustomizeCommandButtonsEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PrevButton.Visible = false;
    }
```

If you only want to hide it on the first page

```
    private void wizardControl1_CustomizeCommandButtons(object sender, CustomizeCommandButtonsEventArgs e)
    {
        if(wizardControl1.SelectedPageIndex == 0)
            e.PrevButton.Visible = false;
    }
```

It seems like it will reset the visibility each time (so you don't need to toggle it back on).  Anyway, I think this is what you're looking for.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraWizardWizardControl_CustomizeCommandButtonstopic

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That looks like it will work.  Unfortunately I have to use an old version of DevExpress that doesn't have that event.  Since you answered my question, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set your own fields to the wizard buttons and then use these anywhere in your code. This will, for example, allow you to hide/disable the "Next" button until all fields page have been completed.

```
    private void NodeConfigurationWizardCustomizeCommandButtons(object sender, CustomizeCommandButtonsEventArgs e)
    {
            _nextButton = e.NextButton;}

        private void GetRowsButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var rowList = ServiceClient.GetAvailableRows();
            var rowsReturned = rowList.Count > 0;
            _nextButton.Button.Enabled = rowsReturned ;}
```